# Change settings of a circle in MVCObject

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using code from this example : https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step6

I want to **change the color of the circle** when user make a dblclick event, but it doesn't work and I don't know how to make. I want to hide/disabled the resize marker after the double click also.

Here my code : http://jsfiddle.net/e4s8P/5/

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dblclick', function() {

      marker.setDraggable(false);
      marker.setVisible(false);

      //change color of the circle here and hide marker of radius


    });
```

Thanks for your help,
Have a nice day!

Comment: what circle? you haven't drawn one!

Comment: Sorry I did not write, but click on the map :)

Comment: i did. it doesn;t work

Comment: Works in Chrome and Firefox.. I just removed the marker on the map, it was a test. (Link updated)

Comment: i'm using firefox and no it still doesn't work

Comment: strange, it works... : http://i.imgur.com/ohpbb2V.png

Comment: not on all versions of firefox.. i'm on firefox 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't understand the accepted answer. To change the colours of an existing circle you need to use the setOptions method on [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle).

e.g.

```
marker.setOptions({
    strokeColor: 'red',
    fillColor: 'red'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's an example of how to change the colour of your circle

```
function DrawCircle(rad) {

rad *= 1600; // convert to meters if in miles
if (draw_circle != null) {
    draw_circle.setMap(null);
}
draw_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: center,
    radius: rad,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#dedede",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map
});
```

or

```
 circleOptions: {
     fillColor: '#dedede'
 }
```

as for removing marker it's just

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dblclick", function() {
    marker.setMap(null);
});
```

Comment: I just can't use setOptions for redefine the color ? And not redraw a circle ?

Comment: will investigate but to redraw is ok

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#fill_color - i know it says android but it works the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer with this example : https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/twittersearch

I changed my code, and it works (but not in jsfiddle) : http://jsfiddle.net/QQbtM/6/

```
see jsfiddle
```